# Performance issues with AWS S3 Java SDK

Tags: aws-java-sdk

We have been using AWS Java SDK S3 APIs to upload and download attachments. Of late experiencing degraded performance while storing and retrieving files from S3 bucket. An intermittent issue under high load was noted in the thread dumps related to the EC2CredentialsFetcher component of the S3 client SDK. We observed that SDK is blocking/taking considerable amount of time in looking-up the credentials from EC2 instance.

We are using AWS Java SDK version - 1.11.731 and below is the code snippet to create AmazonS3 client instance at the startup of application and reused for lifetime of application.

```
AmazonS3ClientBuilder builder = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard();
    AmazonS3 client = builder
                .withClientConfiguration( clientConfigurationInstance )
                .withRegion( getRegion() )
                .withForceGlobalBucketAccessEnabled( true )
                .build();
```

An example of the stack trace given in the thread dump is shown below:

```
"http-apr-8080-exec-82" Id=103100 in BLOCKED on lock=com.amazonaws.auth.EC2CredentialsFetcher@34fe4624
     owned by http-apr-8080-exec-32 Id=20565 BlockedCount : 343, BlockedTime : -1, WaitedCount : 42536, WaitedTime : -1
    at com.amazonaws.auth.EC2CredentialsFetcher.fetchCredentials(EC2CredentialsFetcher.java:112)
    at com.amazonaws.auth.EC2CredentialsFetcher.getCredentials(EC2CredentialsFetcher.java:82)
    at com.amazonaws.auth.InstanceProfileCredentialsProvider.getCredentials(InstanceProfileCredentialsProvider.java:141)
    at com.amazonaws.auth.EC2ContainerCredentialsProviderWrapper.getCredentials(EC2ContainerCredentialsProviderWrapper.java:51)
    at com.amazonaws.auth.AWSCredentialsProviderChain.getCredentials(AWSCredentialsProviderChain.java:110)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.S3CredentialsProviderChain.getCredentials(S3CredentialsProviderChain.java:35)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.getCredentialsFromContext(AmazonHttpClient.java:1119)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.runBeforeRequestHandlers(AmazonHttpClient.java:759)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.doExecute(AmazonHttpClient.java:723)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeWithTimer(AmazonHttpClient.java:716)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:699)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.access$500(AmazonHttpClient.java:667)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutionBuilderImpl.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:649)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:513)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:4221) 
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:4168)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.getObjectMetadata(AmazonS3Client.java:1249)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.getObjectMetadata(AmazonS3Client.java:1224)
```

As suggested by AWS support team and here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/v1/developer-guide/setup-credentials.html#refresh-credentials , we modified client creation code to leverage asynchronous IMDS credential refresh mechanism, as below :

```
AmazonS3ClientBuilder builder = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard();
    builder.setCredentials( InstanceProfileCredentialsProvider.createAsyncRefreshingProvider(true) );
    AmazonS3 client = builder
                .withClientConfiguration( clientConfigurationInstance )
                .withRegion( getRegion() )
                .withForceGlobalBucketAccessEnabled( true )
                .build();
```

The idea is to refresh the credentials in a daemon thread, so that file upload/download API consumer threads wont't be suffered with overhead of refreshing the credentials and hence hoping that end users will not observe any performance issues.

This change didn't result any performance benefits rather introduced other issues in the system with S3 integration. We are observing the below exception from imds-credentials-refresh daemon thread intermittently under high load :

```
    2020-04-24 01:34:59,466 [-credentials-refresh] [          ] [                    ] [                    ] (anceProfileCredentialsProvider) ERROR   - Failed to connect to service endpoint: 
    com.amazonaws.SdkClientException: Failed to connect to service endpoint: 
        at com.amazonaws.internal.EC2ResourceFetcher.doReadResource(EC2ResourceFetcher.java:100) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.731.jar:?]
        at com.amazonaws.internal.EC2ResourceFetcher.doReadResource(EC2ResourceFetcher.java:70) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.731.jar:?]
        at com.amazonaws.internal.InstanceMetadataServiceResourceFetcher.readResource(InstanceMetadataServiceResourceFetcher.java:75) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.731.jar:?]
        at com.amazonaws.internal.EC2ResourceFetcher.readResource(EC2ResourceFetcher.java:66) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.731.jar:?]
        at com.amazonaws.auth.InstanceMetadataServiceCredentialsFetcher.getCredentialsResponse(InstanceMetadataServiceCredentialsFetcher.java:47) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.731.jar:?]
        at com.amazonaws.auth.BaseCredentialsFetcher.fetchCredentials(BaseCredentialsFetcher.java:112) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.731.jar:?]
        at com.amazonaws.auth.BaseCredentialsFetcher.getCredentials(BaseCredentialsFetcher.java:68) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.731.jar:?]
        at com.amazonaws.auth.InstanceProfileCredentialsProvider$2.run(InstanceProfileCredentialsProvider.java:118) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.731.jar:?]
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) ~[?:1.8.0_171]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308) ~[?:1.8.0_171]
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180) ~[?:1.8.0_171]
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294) ~[?:1.8.0_171]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [?:1.8.0_171]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [?:1.8.0_171]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_171]
    Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_171]
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(SocketInputStream.java:116) ~[?:1.8.0_171]
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:171) ~[?:1.8.0_171]
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141) ~[?:1.8.0_171]
        at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:246) ~[?:1.8.0_171]
        at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:286) ~[?:1.8.0_171]
        at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:345) ~[?:1.8.0_171]
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTPHeader(HttpClient.java:735) ~[?:1.8.0_171]
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTP(HttpClient.java:678) ~[?:1.8.0_171]
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1587) ~[?:1.8.0_171]
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1492) ~[?:1.8.0_171]
        at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:480) ~[?:1.8.0_171]
        at com.amazonaws.internal.EC2ResourceFetcher.doReadResource(EC2ResourceFetcher.java:82) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.731.jar:?]
        ... 14 more
```

The exception has occurred relatively at high frequency, 1,074 times across 5 instances over a weekend.
Q#1) Does it have any impact on uploading/downloading files using the Java SDK AmazonS3 client (mentioned above)? What could the root cause behind these socket timeouts be? What should our next steps to resolve it be? Is it an issue with S3 SDK or with EC2 & IMDS connectivity ?

Also, intermittently under high load unable to upload/download files and the below exception is observed while trying to download the file :

```
java.io.IOException: Cannot find S3 object at /Production/prod1/filestorage/attachments/email-content-1587156640090_MM-6248348.html
        at com.myorg.internal.cloud.aws.s3.S3WrapperInputStream.startRead(S3WrapperInputStream.java:142)
        at com.myorg.internal.cloud.aws.s3.S3WrapperInputStream.read(S3WrapperInputStream.java:116)
        ...
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    Caused by: com.amazonaws.SdkClientException: Failed to connect to service endpoint: 
        at com.amazonaws.internal.EC2ResourceFetcher.doReadResource(EC2ResourceFetcher.java:100)
        at com.amazonaws.internal.EC2ResourceFetcher.doReadResource(EC2ResourceFetcher.java:70)
        at com.amazonaws.internal.InstanceMetadataServiceResourceFetcher.readResource(InstanceMetadataServiceResourceFetcher.java:75)
        at com.amazonaws.internal.EC2ResourceFetcher.readResource(EC2ResourceFetcher.java:66)
        at com.amazonaws.auth.InstanceMetadataServiceCredentialsFetcher.getCredentialsResponse(InstanceMetadataServiceCredentialsFetcher.java:47)
        at com.amazonaws.auth.BaseCredentialsFetcher.fetchCredentials(BaseCredentialsFetcher.java:112)
        at com.amazonaws.auth.BaseCredentialsFetcher.getCredentials(BaseCredentialsFetcher.java:68)
        at com.amazonaws.auth.InstanceProfileCredentialsProvider.getCredentials(InstanceProfileCredentialsProvider.java:166)
        at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.getCredentialsFromContext(AmazonHttpClient.java:1251)
        at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeOneRequest(AmazonHttpClient.java:1272)
        at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:1139)
        at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.doExecute(AmazonHttpClient.java:796)
        at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeWithTimer(AmazonHttpClient.java:764)
        at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:738)
        at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.access$500(AmazonHttpClient.java:698)
        at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutionBuilderImpl.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:680)
        at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:544)
        at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:524)
        at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:5052)
        at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:4998)
        at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.getObject(AmazonS3Client.java:1486)
        at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.getObject(AmazonS3Client.java:1341)
        at com.myorg.internal.cloud.aws.s3.S3WrapperInputStream.startRead(S3WrapperInputStream.java:134)
        ... 198 more
    Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(SocketInputStream.java:116)
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:171)
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
        at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:246)
        at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:286)
        at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:345)
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTPHeader(HttpClient.java:735)
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTP(HttpClient.java:678)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1587)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1492)
        at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:480)
        at com.amazonaws.internal.EC2ResourceFetcher.doReadResource(EC2ResourceFetcher.java:82)
        ... 220 more
```

Q#2) After enabling the asynchronous refresh of IMDS credentials, does every or any create/get file API calls looks-up credentials from IMDS?
Q#3) How to avoid the timeouts and achieve relatively quicker turnaround consistently for API calls?
Q#4) As per https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/instancedata-data-retrieval.html#instancedata-throttling , instance metadata service is being throttled. How to avoid this or address the associated issues?

Thanks,
Chandra

Comment: Hi! I talked about this issue and described our custom solution [in this article](https://medium.com/expedia-group-tech/service-slow-to-retrieve-aws-credentials-ebc02a38e95b).

Comment: Just a thought: Have you checked if the _maxConnections_ setting of your AWSClients ClientConfiguration matches your use case? I think it defaults to 50 connections, so with a concurrency of >50, you will have SDK calls waiting for a free connection to actually issue a request against AWS. Should not cause timeouts but might slow down commands (there is a 10 second timeout and internal retries, so this might not even surface as an exception thrown by the client).